# Parsing the return of SQLite Query in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have an SQLite database in a Flask (Python) web application and this is my code to see if an email has already registered (in my application.py file). It returns a boolean (1 or 0) if it exists or not, respectively.

```
db = SQL("sqlite:///test.db")

exists = db.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM people WHERE email in (?))", (email@domain.com))
```

Where `print(exists)` returns:

```
[{"EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM people WHERE email in ('email@domain.com'))": 1}]
```

In short, I get the required result (tested with unregistered and registered emails), but I don't know how to access this value of 1 or 0.

Would appreciate any ideas a lot.

Comment: have you tried checking if exists is = to True or False?

Comment: What is `db`?  Please provide a [mre], as it is now, your code isn't even valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to alias the exists part of your select query

```py
exists = db.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM people WHERE email in (?)) as email_exists", (email@domain.com))
        print(exists[0])
```

then you should be able to access the value by `exists[0]['email_exists']`. This will give you `1` or `0` which you can next convert to `bool`.

```py
exists = db.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM people WHERE email in (?)) as email_exists", (email@domain.com))
        print(bool(exists[0]['email_exists']))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!